# Is possible to convert a Flux to Mono

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, webflux

I playing around with r2dc for spring boot java application.

I was thinking if possible to convert a Flux to Mono for certain calculation.

Pseudo example:

```
static PseudoMagic calculate(List<Foo> foos) {
   return callTheMagicRutine(foos)
}

Mono<PseudoMagic> getMyMagic() {
   Flux<Foo> foos = getMyFoos()
   foos.transformToMagic(f -> calculator(f))
}
```

Comment: Flux::collectToList

Comment: but than I lose the reactive part :( ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [collectList()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#collectList--) method in `Flux` to transform the `Flux<Foo>` to `Mono<List<Foo>>`. That is the best you can do.